# Trying to use block of html in span to set img alt tag for multiple images on page.

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I hope the title is self explanatory.

Here is my HTML (there are many of these items):

```
<div class="shopTextWrapper">
                <div class="shop_item"> 
                    <a href="#dialog2" name="modal">
                    <img src="objetdart/images_sm/ethanol-i.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a> 
                </div>
                <br clear="all" />
                <p class="desc_text">
                Ethanol
                </p>
            </div>
```

My current jQuery (not working):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('img').each(function(){
    var $altText = $(this).find('div p.desc_text');
    $('img').attr('alt', $altText);
    });
});
```

I need to find each span desc_text which is contained inside a parent div which also contains the appropriate image. I am currently returning object Object.

Any ideas how to get the title for the image that is contained within the shopTextWrapper div?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('img').each(function(){
    var $altText = $(this).closest('div.shopTextWrapper').find(".desc_text").text();
    $(this).attr('alt', $altText);
    });
```

Comment: Seems to be returning alt="", can't get the desc_text into the variable.

Comment: Haha, thank you, I started creating a jsfiddle and then saw the code was working, but you edited your answer and I was using the older code. Thank you. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U2UQU/3/

Comment: if you have many "shopTextWrapper" divs , then better to use closest than parents. check parents and closest on google.

Comment: Thank you, yes I do have alot of shopTextWrappers and I was not aware of closest, that is excellent.

Comment: nice.. to hear, it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var $altText = $(this).parents('.shop_item').next($('p.desc_text')).text();
```

Comment: Seems to be returning: <img src="objetdart/images_sm/pills-i.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt=""> in Chrome.